# Can I use Beautiful Soup to get an XML file from the web that's displayed using HTML?

Tags: python, html, xml, beautifulsoup

I have a url here that contains the contents of an XML file, but it is not technically an XML file in itself:
http://auxopsweb2.oit.nd.edu/DiningMenus/api/Menus/46

I wanted to use the Beautiful Soup library in python to try to pull some of the data from the XML contents. However, I only know how to pull the data as the HTML that is displaying the page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

res = requests.get("http://auxopsweb2.oit.nd.edu/DiningMenus/api/Menus/46")
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs(res.text , 'html.parser')
```

This makes it hard to search through since all of the data is actually unlabeled `<span>` elements. Is there a way to bypass the HTML and just pull the straight XML contents? I've never really worked with BeautifulSoup before, so sorry if my question is ignorant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, req
url = 'http://auxopsweb2.oit.nd.edu/DiningMenus/api/Menus/46'
html = req.get(url)
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
MenuCourses = doc.selects('ServiceMenu').selects('MenuCourse')
print(MenuCourses.Name.text)
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Answer (score 0):

below (you get the data as json and work with a dict)

```
import requests
import pprint

r = requests.get('http://auxopsweb2.oit.nd.edu/DiningMenus/api/Menus/46')
if r.status_code == 200:
    data = r.json()
    pprint.pprint(data)
else:
    print('Failed to read data: {}'.format(r.status_code))
```